# Azure Release Pipeline - How to Set Agent Pool

Tags: azure, devops, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, agent

I am using Azure Classic UI to setup Release pipeline. I have 2 stages in a pipeline to reflect TEST and PRD. Also I am using self hosted agents to do build and release.

I have 2 Release Agent Pools (One for doing TEST and one for doing PRD releases) at Org level with a single agent in each. Each of these Agents is running on separate self hosted servers. Additionally I have another Agent Pool with single agent in it running build pipeline runs.

In the project I have a single release pipeline with 2 stages TEST and PRD. I want to be able to utilize the TEST Agent Pool for TEST stage and PRD for PRD stage. But I cant seem to define it anywhere. Is this possible ? I mean I can add an Agent Job in the pipeline where I can select one of the Agent Pools but When I add a Deployment group, I cant specify which Release Agent pool to use. It only does it by Deployment Group and I don't know if I can specify Deployment groups to run on a specific Release Agent ?

The Short of it is, how can I configure entire release pipeline to run on a specific Release Agent Pool ? Or define a specific stage of a pipeline to run on a specific Release Agent ? Maybe I am not understanding how release pipelines run. Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you checked the following replies? Are they helpful?

Answer (score 3):

You can create agents for TEST and PROD in agent pools .You can go to Organization/ Project settings --> Agent pools --> create New Agent Pool for Test and PROD agents as shown https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser . Agents shows when it is Online /Offline Status to run the Jobs in Release pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a misunderstanding of Deployment Group. A deployment group is a logical set of deployment target machines that have agents installed on each one. Every target machine in the deployment group has installed a build and release agent. A deployment group is just another grouping of agents, much like an agent pool. It's not need to select agent for a deployment group.

Check following documentation for more details of deployment group:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops